# Debugging Applications Running in a Singularity Container in an IDE

Tags: debugging, container

I am developing algorithms within the framework of Tensorflow (custom OPs and graphs) within a Singularity container (with Ubuntu 20.04, CUDA 11.2 and the Tensorflow 2.4 library). I understand that within a container, we can still use GDB/CUDA-GDB to debug our applications on command line. However, debugging on command line is very inconvenient for a large group of engineers in a large department. Is there a way to debug applications running in a Singularity container from an IDE such as Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it (and I haven't even tried VS on Linux),  but theoretically if you install the IDE inside the container, and then you start a container [instance](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.1/user-guide/cli/singularity_instance_start.html#singularity-instance-start), run the application inside, and then connect to the same instance and try running an IDE, I don't see a reason why it wouldn't work. You should be able to run inside a Singularity container anything you run on a bare metal host.